# Get-ADUser Filter comparison

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm beginning in PowerShell and trying to make this line working :

```
(Get-ADUser -Filter {userPrincipalName -eq $($ListUsers[100].UserPrincipalName)} -SearchBase "..." -Properties *).distinguishedName
```

I tried a lot of different things but nothing worked.

The call of `$ListUsers[100].UserPrincipalName)` works 100% sure, I tried it outside of the line, so it's just a logical or syntaxic problem.

Could someone tell me how to get it to work ? Thanks

Comment: Also have a look at the addition I made to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes.

The `-Filter` argument to the `Get-AD*` cmdlets takes a string (!), not a script block (even though it looks like it, because braces can also be used instead of quotes).

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName -eq '$($ListUsers[100].UserPrincipalName)'"
```

This way you get proper variable substitution. Note you must end up with a valid filter string, so putting single quotes around the values is necessary when those values are strings.

---

If you have many objects to fetch from AD, it can be beneficial to fetch them all in one go, instead of one-by-one in a loop. Consider this:

```
$ListUsers = @(<# ...list of items... #>)

# build LDAP filter string
$upn_filter = $ListUsers.UserPrincipalName -join ')(userPrincipalName='
$upn_filter = "(|(userPrincipalName=$upn_filter))"

$users = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $upn_filter
$users.distinguishedName
```

This builds an LDAP filter in the following form:

```
(|(userPrincipalName=A)(userPrincipalName=B)(userPrincipalName=C)(userPrincipalName=D))
```

which would be able to fetch 4 matching objects from AD in one step. Of course you can also build a "PowerShell-style" filter string, but I find the LDAP syntax a lot easier to handle, and it's shorter.

LDAP filter strings can get pretty long without the server complaining, and doing only one round-trip to the domain controller saves time.

Comment: The total size of an LDAP query (not just the query string) can be [up to 10MB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/556711/1202807), which is pretty huge. Still, I have some sample code [here](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html#ask-for-as-much-as-you-can-at-a-time) that shows how to break up the request in blocks of 50 (or any number you want). The code is C#, but it could be translated to PowerShell (PowerShell arrays implement .NET's `IEnumerable`).

Comment: @GabrielLuci Nice, that's my own question you're linking to. :)

Comment: Ha! I didn't even notice. It's awesome when things are still relevant after 10 years :)

Comment: Nice; re "putting single quotes around the values is necessary": worth mentioning that embedded _double_ quotes are also an option - while they need to be escaped, they are helpful for expanded values that may contain single quotes (apostrophes).